# My Baum-Welch algorithm is very slow. Is it due to Mathematica?

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review, markov-chains

I've also posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136524/baum-welch-algorithm-in-mathematica-seems-to-be-very-slow-why), since I'm not sure which community is more adequate for this type of question.

I've programmed *imperatively* the Baum-Welch algorithm for a 2 state hidden Markov model (HMM), as is explained in this [book](http://en.bookfi.org/book/667970). When I try it with a size sample of 100, I usually get a decent estimate after 18 seconds. However, when I use a sample size of 500, it takes me between 290-350 seconds to get an improved estimation of the HMM parameters.

I get the impression the algorithm should not perform this badly. However I'm not sure why it does.

One thing I've discovered is that *Mathematica* is more functional oriented, so when I program iteratively I'm losing some computation 'power'. But is this really enough for this bad performance??

What is your experience with this algorithm?

I'm using as stopping criterion when the norm of the difference between the current estimate and the previous one is less than $10^{-3}$. This criterion just seemed simple enough. I'm also trying to use other stopping criteria, but it doesn't seems to alter much. The problem is each iteration of the algorithm, in a sample size of 500, takes almost 20 seconds more or less... This worries me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
EM1[y_, ite_] := 
Module[{n, listainicial, teta0, teta1, teta2, likeham, likehamtotal,
 pimattotal, sigmatotal, tetatotal, θk1, θk2, 
listak, listbk, fikyj, iterations},
n = Length[y] - 1;
listainicial = N[Table[0, {j, 1, n}]];
pimattotal = listainicial;
tetatotal = listainicial;
sigmatotal = listainicial;
likehamtotal = listainicial;

likeham[pimat_, fiyj_] := Module[{pizero, Pmat, counter, mult},
 pizero = pimat[[1]];
 Pmat = {pimat[[2]], pimat[[3]]};
 counter = 1;
 mult = IdentityMatrix[2];
 While[counter <= n,
  mult = 
   Dot[mult, 
    Dot[Pmat, {{fiyj[[1, counter]], 0}, {0, fiyj[[2, counter]]}}]];
  counter = counter + 1;
  ];
 Dot[Dot[pizero, mult], {1, 1}]
 ];

iterations = 1;
While[iterations <= ite,
(*initialization*)

pim0 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
pim1 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
pim2 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];

pimatk = N[{{pim0, 1 - pim0}, {pim1, 1 - pim1}, {pim2, 1 - pim2}}];
fikyj = N[Table[Table[1/n, {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, 2}]];

ak = N[Table[Table[0.1, {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, 2}]];
bk = N[Table[Table[1, {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, 2}]];
θk1 = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
θk2 = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5};

listak = listainicial;
listbk = listainicial;


While[Norm[θk1 - θk2] > 10^-3,

 θk1 = θk2;

 ak[[1, 1]] = pimatk[[1, 1]]*fikyj[[1, 1]];
 ak[[2, 1]] = pimatk[[1, 2]]*fikyj[[2, 1]];

  ak[[1, 1]] = ak[[1, 1]];
  ak[[2, 1]] = ak[[2, 1]];

 (*Induction*)
 counterE = 1;
 While [counterE <= n - 1,
  ak[[1, 
    counterE + 
     1]] = (pimatk[[1 + 1, 1]]*ak[[1, counterE]] + 
      pimatk[[2 + 1, 1]]*ak[[2, counterE]])*
    fikyj[[1, counterE + 1]];
  ak[[2, 
    counterE + 
     1]] = (pimatk[[1 + 1, 2]]*ak[[1, counterE]] + 
      pimatk[[2 + 1, 2]]*ak[[2, counterE]])*
    fikyj[[2, counterE + 1]];

   ak[[1, counterE + 1]] = ak[[1, counterE + 1]];
   ak[[2, counterE + 1]] = ak[[2, counterE + 1]];

  bk[[1, n - counterE]] = 
   pimatk[[1 + 1, 1]]*fikyj[[1, n - counterE + 1]]*
     bk[[1, n - counterE + 1]] + 
    pimatk[[1 + 1, 2]]*fikyj[[2, n - counterE + 1]]*
     bk[[2, n - counterE + 1]];
  bk[[2, n - counterE]] = 
   pimatk[[2 + 1, 1]]*fikyj[[1, n - counterE + 1]]*
     bk[[1, n - counterE + 1]] + 
    pimatk[[2 + 1, 2]]*fikyj[[2, n - counterE + 1]]*
     bk[[2, n - counterE + 1]];

  bk[[1, n - counterE]] = bk[[1, n - counterE]];
   bk[[2, n - counterE]] = bk[[2, n - counterE]];

  counterE = counterE + 1;
  ];

 τhijk = 
  Table[Table[
    Table[(ak[[h, j]]*pimatk[[h + 1, i]]*fikyj[[i, j + 1]]*
        bk[[i, j + 1]])/(Sum[
        Sum[ak[[hh, j]]*pimatk[[hh + 1, ii]]*fikyj[[ii, j + 1]]*
          bk[[ii, j + 1]], {ii, 1, 2}], {hh, 1, 2}]), {j, 1, 
      n - 1}], {i, 1, 2}], {h, 1, 2}];
 τijk = 
  Table[Table[
    ak[[i, j]]*
     bk[[i, j]]/(Sum[
        ak[[h, j]]*10^listak[[j]]*bk[[h, j]], {h, 1, 2}]), {j, 1, 
     n}], {i, 1, 2}];

 (*M-step*)

 teta0 = (Sum[
     Sum[(Sum[
          y[[j + 1]]*τijk[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}])*τijk[[i, 
         k]]*y[[k]]/(Sum[τijk[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}]) - 
       y[[k + 1]]*y[[k]]*τijk[[i, k]], {i, 1, 2}], {k, 1, 
      n}])/(Sum[
     Sum[(Sum[
           y[[j]]*τijk[[i, j]], {j, 1, 
            n}]/(Sum[τijk[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}]) - 
         y[[k]])*τijk[[i, k]]*y[[k]], {i, 1, 2}], {k, 1, n}]);

 teta1 = 
  Sum[τijk[[1, j]]*(y[[j + 1]] - teta0*y[[j]]), {j, 1, n}]/
   Sum[τijk[[1, j]], {j, 1, n}];

 teta2 = 
  Sum[τijk[[2, j]]*(y[[j + 1]] - teta0*y[[j]]), {j, 1, n}]/
   Sum[τijk[[2, j]], {j, 1, n}];

 sigmaest = 
  Sqrt[Sum[((y[[j + 1]] - teta1 - teta0*y[[j]])^2*τijk[[1, 
         j]] + (y[[j + 1]] - teta2 - teta0*y[[j]])^2*τijk[[2,
          j]]), {j, 1, n}]/(n)];

 θk2 = {teta0, teta1, teta2};

 (*Q[θ_,σ_]:=(τijk[[1,1]]*Log[pimatk[[1,
 1]]]+τijk[[2,1]]*Log[pimatk[[1,2]]])+Sum[Sum[
 Sum[τhijk[[h,i,j]]*Log[pimatk[[h+1,i]]],{j,1,n-1}],{i,1,
 2}],{h,1,2}]+Sum[Sum[τijk[[i,j]]*Log[1/(Sqrt[2*
 Pi]*σ)]*(-(y[[j+1]]-θ[[i+1]]-θ[[1]]*y[[
 j]])^2/(2*σ^2)),{j,1,n}],{i,1,2}];*)

 (*updates on remaining parameters*)
 pimatk[[1, 1]] = τijk[[1, 1]];
 pimatk[[1, 2]] = τijk[[2, 1]];(*π_ 0i=τijk[[i,
 1]]*)

 pimatk[[2, 1]] = 
  Sum[τhijk[[1, 1, j]], {j, 1, n - 1}]/
   Sum[τijk[[1, j]], {j, 2, n}];
 pimatk[[2, 2]] = 
  Sum[τhijk[[1, 2, j]], {j, 1, n - 1}]/
   Sum[τijk[[1, j]], {j, 2, n}];
 pimatk[[3, 1]] = 
  Sum[τhijk[[2, 1, j]], {j, 1, n - 1}]/
   Sum[τijk[[2, j]], {j, 2, n}];
 pimatk[[3, 2]] = 
  Sum[τhijk[[2, 2, j]], {j, 1, n - 1}]/
   Sum[τijk[[2, j]], {j, 2, n}];(*π_hi=(\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(j = 2\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(τ\), \(hij\)]\))/\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(j = 2\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(τ\), \(hj\)]\)*)
 (*Print["pimatk =",pimatk];*)

 counterM = 1;
 While[counterM <= n,
  fikyj[[1, counterM]] = (1/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*sigmaest))*
    E^(-(y[[counterM + 1]] - θk2[[2]] - θk2[[1]]*
            y[[counterM]])^2/(2*sigmaest^2));

  fikyj[[2, counterM]] = (1/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*sigmaest))*
    E^(-(y[[counterM + 1]] - θk2[[3]] - θk2[[1]]*
            y[[counterM]])^2/(2*sigmaest^2));
  counterM = counterM + 1;

  ];


 ];

likehamtotal[[iterations]] = likeham[pimatk, fikyj];
pimattotal[[iterations]] = pimatk;
tetatotal[[iterations]] = θk2;
sigmatotal[[iterations]] = sigmaest;

iterations = iterations + 1;
];

iterations = 1;
pos = 1;
While[iterations <= ite ,
If[likehamtotal[[iterations]] > likehamtotal[[pos]],
 pos = iterations];
iterations = iterations + 1
];
{pimattotal[[pos]], tetatotal[[pos]], sigmatotal[[pos]]}
];
```

Comment: Can you post your code? We can't really help you otherwise!

Comment: @blochwave Thanks for your interest. I've just posted my code.

Comment: That is a lot of code for anyone on this site to have time to read/critique/analyze it fully and most likely, no one is going to. However from a quick glance at the code, I can most certainly say that the slowness is due to the procedural programming style. All those `Sum[Sum[Sum[Sum...` terms in nested `While`s are bound to give terrible performance. Writing the algorithm in a functional manner would certainly speed things up a lot. Unfortunately, it is hard (for me at least) to recommend specific changes to make to your code. If I were you, I'd start afresh with functional (use Igor's link)

Comment: I was about to comment on the nested `Sum[Sum[Sum[...`s!

Comment: I would really like to see a `Compile`d version of this though. I think it could be pretty fast. I don't see anything that can't be compiled to C.

Comment: @rm -rf. You're probably right. I've eliminated as many sum as I could, and now it takes only 5-10 seconds with 500 size sample. =D

But it's still too much. This first code was just a literal translation of the mathematical formulas... I guess I have to start afresh...

Comment: @Pickett I'm trying to use the Compile function to increase the speed of this algorithm. It runs, but after a few iterations, I get the following error: CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression {{{1.,1.84962*10^-29},{0.643248,0.356752},{0.278529,0.721471}},{0.897627,-<<19>>,3.08828},0.998826} should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers. >>

What does this mean??

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Hard to say, I dislike those messages. I don't have a lot of experience with `Compile`, I only know it works wonders for speed. What I try to do when I use it is to compile small functions, I don't put the whole block of code inside `Compile`. So I end up with many `Compile` - makes it more debuggable. Easier to understand where the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very clear description of a Mathematica implementation of BW is given by Robert J Frey [here.](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~frey/QuantitativeFinance/Resources/TutorialsWorkshops/Tutorial_HMM/HMMUG_20091222_05.pdf) He seems to not have performance issues.

Comment: I Thank you for our interest. I'm definitely going to take a look at Frey's solution. However, it seems to rely mainly on functional programming. So, this doesn't answer my question. This is more a comment than an answer to my question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't necessarily disagree, however here the OP knows what the BW algorithm does, and the implementation is nontrivial, so it seems cumbersome to reproduce it here.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better as a comment to the question.

Comment: @IgorRivin Please participate here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1395/193

Comment: @Belisarius OK, done :)

Comment: @IgorRivin Thanks a lot :)

Comment: (Just so you know, some of these comments are automatically generated from the `/review` queue). To commenters and flaggers: the "commentness" of the answer is noted and I think we all (including Igor) agree on that. However, Igor also has a valid point that the link does answer the question fully and reproducing the code there (which is a lot) is kinda futile. Please participate in the meta discussion if you have thoughts/more to say on this. I will not be deleting this answer.